# How to plot multiple dataframes into a single figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have problems in plotting multiple charts on the same one as follows:

```
plt.title("Food distribution across countries ")

df1.groupby('Date').size().plot()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

df2.groupby('Date').size().plot()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

df3.groupby('Date').size().plot()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

An example of dataset is

```
df1
        Date                                              
    0     03/26/2020  bread   
    1     03/21/2020  bread   
    2     03/14/2020  prawns   
    3     03/13/2020  eggs   
    4     01/20/2020  prawns   
    ...          ...                                                  
    1033  04/08/2020  chicken   
    1034  04/08/2020  ham  
    1035  04/08/2020  ham   
    1036  04/08/2020  ham   
    1037  04/08/2020  honey

df2
        Date                                              
    0     03/26/2020  bread   
    1     03/21/2020  honey   
    2     03/14/2020  milk   
    3     03/13/2020  eggs   
    4     01/20/2020  prawns   
    ...          ...                                                  
    1033  04/08/2020  chocolate   
    1034  04/08/2020  chocolate  
    1035  04/08/2020  sausage   
    1036  04/08/2020  ham   
    1037  04/08/2020  butter


df3
        Date                                             
    0     03/26/2020  bread   
    1     03/21/2020  honey   
    2     03/14/2020  milk   
    3     03/13/2020  milk   
    4     01/20/2020  beer   
    ...          ...                                                   
    1033  04/08/2020  chocolate   
    1034  04/08/2020  sausage  
    1035  04/08/2020  ham   
    1036  04/08/2020  ham   
    1037  04/08/2020  honey
```

I would like to plot three line charts in the same plot to show an overlapping in data across time.

Is there any way (even different from what I have been trying) to have one only chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a single df and plot it

```
timeline_df = pd.concat(
    [df1.groupby('Date').size(), df2...],
    axis=1)
timeline_df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
timeline_df.plot()
```

Answer (score 2):

- Plot the dataframes on the same `axes`, by using the `ax` parameter of [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df1.groupby('Date').size().plot(ax=ax, label='df1')
df2.groupby('Date').size().plot(ax=ax, label='df2')
df3.groupby('Date').size().plot(ax=ax, label='df3')
plt.legend()
```

### Example

- This example plots 10 separate dataframes onto a single plot.
- The dataframes are in the `dict`, `planets_dict`.
- Dataframes can also be placed in a `list`, which can be iterated through.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load test data as a pandas dataframe
planets = sns.load_dataset('planets')

# display(planets.head(3))
            method  number  orbital_period  mass  distance  year
0  Radial Velocity       1         269.300  7.10     77.40  2006
1  Radial Velocity       1         874.774  2.21     56.95  2008
2  Radial Velocity       1         763.000  2.60     19.84  2011

# get unique methods
methods = planets.method.unique()

# use a dict comprehension to create 10 separate dataframes, 1 for each method
planets_dict = {k: planets[planets.method == k] for k in methods}

# create a color map so each dataframe will be a different color
colors = sns.color_palette('husl', n_colors=len(methods))  # get a number of colors
cmap = dict(zip(methods, colors)) 

# create fig and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# iterate through each of the dataframes and add it to the same plt
for k, v in planets_dict.items():
    v.plot(kind='scatter', x='distance', y='orbital_period', ax=ax, label=k, color=cmap[k])

# style formatting
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylabel('Orbital Period (Earth Days)')
plt.xlabel('Light Years from Earth')
plt.legend(title='Discovery Method', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]